# Browser freezes when I execute this simple code to increment number

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a div where the number starts from 1 and automatically increments by one - like a stopwatch. But when I run the code, it crashes or does not work.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div></div>
    <script>
      var div = document.querySelector('div');
      var i = 1;
      while(i>0){
        div.innerText=i;
        i++;
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You never let the JavaScript engine rest. As soon as it has incremented the variable, the loop starts over, and it never exits. This blocks everything else.

You need to pause between loops to let the browser do other things.

You can use the `requestAnimationFrame` function to do this.

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
let i = 1;
const incrementCounter = () => {
  div.innerText = i;
  i++;
  requestAnimationFrame(incrementCounter);
}

incrementCounter();
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned the term "stopwatch" maybe you prefer something like this:
This increments i by 1 every second using `setInterval()`

The first parameter is our function, that gets executed on that interval.
The second parameter `1000` is the interval. In this case 1000 ms.
You can adjust it as needed.

You can stop the timer with:

```
clearInterval(incrementCounter);
```

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');
let i = 1;

const incrementCounter = setInterval(() => {
    div.innerText = i;
    i++;
},1000);
```

```html
<div></div>
```

You can find more information here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

Comment: `setInterval` timers are **highly** unreliable for precision. It only guarantees that the funciton will run after **at least** one second has passed. If you need to solve this sort of problem **and** so something after a certain amount of time has passed, then use `requestAnimationFrame` and make use of the timestamp passed to the callback function.